# How to handle 404 response with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get 404 status when the user id doesn't exist in the database but when I provide a non-existing ID to my API it throws a 500 status error instead of 404!

```
app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    const _id = req.params.id

    User.findById(_id).then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).send()
        }

        return res.send(user)
    }).catch((error) => {
        return res.status(500).send(error)
    })
})
```

How can I handle 404 response with mongoose?
User is a mongoose model

Comment: It's probably throwing an error because the `_id` should be the type `ObjectId` and your *non-existing ID* is can not be converted to `ObjectId`. You can use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(_id)` to check whether it's valid and handle it accordingly

Comment: @thammada mongoose handles this. If you pass ObjectID type it throws an error. The argument passed must be a single string.

Comment: @thammada Apparently, not any string can be converted into ObjectID. It has to be in a specific format to be converted to that type. It can't accept like 1234 as an ID and convert it to ObjectID. That's why it's throwing an error. I was able to get 404 by changing existing IDs to non-existing in my database while preserving the format!

Comment: Yes `req.params.id` is always a string, you can check whether it's a correct format using the function I suggested earlier.

Comment: So you still want to return 500 when there is an incorrectly formatted ID ?

Comment: @thammada no I was unaware that I had to preserve the ObjectID format. When I gave an ID with the format that didn't existed in the database it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
User.findById(_id).exec((user) => {
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).send()
        }

        return res.send(user)
    }).catch((error) => {
        return res.status(500).send(error)
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't quite work! I found what was wrong. The explanation is in the comments under the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an id that does not match mongoose Id, you get 500 error, specifically "Cast Error". to handle it, in catch block:

```
if (err.name === "CastError") {
    const message = `Resource not found. Invalid ID`;
    return res.status(400).send(message)
  }
```